# ServiceWorker idle Timeout too aggressive on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebase, web-applications, service-worker

I've also opened a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1378587) as that browser seems to be substantially more aggressive in it's ServiceWorker timeout enforcement than Chrome, Opera, or the Android browser. I'm putting this out to a broader audience here as I believe that ServiceWorker idle-timeout needs a sharper tool than a pretty blunt "30 seconds".

Shouldn't CPU and Memory load be taken into account? Recharging -vs- not-recharging?

Look I don't have a horse in the race and don't really care other than "I think 1min would be a lot more useful" but are others currently confecting SW interaction to extend longevity?

I am 100% ALL for the ability for a UA to kill a SW at will ANY time. I 100% am NOT asking for extended trans-SW-instance memory or Fat-SW syndrome! Just asking why kill it if we've got heaps of memory and CPU?